# How to activate maven profile setting based on JDK vendor

Tags: java, maven

My `~/.m2/settings.xml` file has a profile that I want to activate only when a specific vendor JDK is used. I read about `<activation>` tag in maven [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#activation), but it seems this tag doesn't have checks by the particular vendor. Any advice on how I can do it?

Comment: May I ask what the rationale behind the desired behaviour is? Normally, all JDKs that pass the JCK should be relaceable by each other without the need to change anything.

Comment: Didn't know that fact. So I will use my client's JDK for my pet projects then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test the `java.vendor` property with something like:

```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>AdoptOpenJDK</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>java.vendor</name>
          <value>AdoptOpenJDK</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
    </profile>
    ...
  </profiles>
```

Use `java -XshowSettings:properties` to determine the property values for
your various JDKs:

```sh
$ java -XshowSettings:properties
Property settings:
    ...
    java.vendor = AdoptOpenJDK
    ...
```